# Are damage bonuses for a weapon doubled for 2[W] rolls?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons, damage

I am a dwarf fighter with a +1 greataxe, and Dwarven Weapon Training (+2 damage).

For a 1[W] damage I assume I roll 1d12+3, but for a 2[W] attack do I roll 2d12 and add 6?

Any help on this would be awesome.

Answer (score 11):

When you see **[W]** in a damage expression, it just means the weapon die as per the basic equipment description. For your character with the greataxe, that means **2[W]** equals **2d12**

All the bonuses add afterwards, they are not multiplied. Bonuses from feats and equipment are not included in the damage descriptions of powers, but how to add them is described elsewhere in the rules. For example, if you have the compendium look up "enhancement bonus" in the glossary.

Most powers, including Basic Melee attacks, will also add a stat bonus (Strength bonus by default for Basic Melee, and for most Fighter powers). So your damage with a 2[W] power is likely to be **2d12+7** or higher (it will be 2d12, +1, +2, +Strength mod)

---

From comments (Mooing Duck): There might be one or two exceptions to this general rule for damage bonuses. But you are safe in assuming that a bonus to weapon damage adds once (and not per die) unless you see the exception written for that specific bonus.

Comment: I think there's a ranger power that gives them a +1 bonus to each "weapon dice" or somesuch, but that's an exception to the rule.

Answer (score -1):

**[W]** means the damage die of the weapon including static bonuses. Static bonuses are magical enhancement bonuses on the weapon, any such damage boosters such as dragonshards, which **are augmented to the weapon**

Comment: Are you saying dragon shard bonuses and enhancement bonuses are counted per [W]? Because that would be incorrect